# Checking If Data in One Table Is Contained in Another

Tags: sql, subquery, subset

```
declare @q table (A int);
declare @a table (B int);

insert into @q select 1 union select 2 union select 3;
insert into @a select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4;
```

I want to know if the data of @q's column A is a subset of @a's column B.

This produces an error.

```
if (select A from @q) in (select B from @a)
print 'yes' else print 'no';
```

This works, but is it the best way of finding out?

```
if (select count(*) from @q) = (select count(*) from @q inner join @a on A = B)
print 'yes' else print 'no';
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using EXCEPT.

```
SELECT ColumnA
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT ColumnB
FROM TableB
```

It will give you a list of everything that's in A that's not in B.

You can insert the result from the above into a table variable, and then check its COUNT (0 = subset, anything else is not subset).

Comment: This is elegant, and you can use `exists ()` to check the count.

Answer (score 0):

Try following. This basically looks for anything that is in @q but not in @a and gets its count. If the count is more than 0 then it returns No otherwise Yes.

```
SELECT CASE 
      WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 'No'
      ELSE 'Yes'
   END 
FROM @q q
LEFT JOIN @a a
ON q.A = a.B 
WHERE a.B iS NULL
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not bad, also check out the answer with `except`.

Comment: If performance is not an issue for you EXCEPT is the way to go. I think LEFT JOIN will be faster for large tables. I guess you can run a test for your scenario. Look at this [url](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic541726-338-1.aspx). I know it doesn't matter in your scenario but other point to note is that EXCEPT will return you DISTINCT rows.